# Program gives error after exe is created in VS

Tags: c#, exe

The following is code in button login on a login form in my project.  As part of the form, a txt file is created containing login details for database.  The project runs fine if I was to just run from visual studio, However after I create an exe with VS, I get error saying connection.txt is not accessible.
Thank you.

```
private void btnlogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {   
        // if the file doesn't exist.
        string fromConnFile = File.ReadAllText("connection.txt");
        NetworkConn ncBefore = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NetworkConn>(fromConnFile);
        String serverName = Base64.base64decode(ncBefore.servername);
        String userName = Base64.base64decode(ncBefore.username);
        String passWord = Base64.base64decode(ncBefore.password);
        String dataBase = Base64.base64decode(ncBefore.database);
        NetworkConn ncAfter = new NetworkConn()
        {   
            servername = serverName,
            username = userName,
            password = passWord,
            database = dataBase
        };
        String user = txtusername.Text.TrimStart().TrimEnd();
        String pass = txtpassword.Text.TrimStart().TrimEnd();
        // object for connecting database.
        MysqlQuery dataQuery = new MysqlQuery(serverName, userName, passWord, dataBase);
        DataTable userInfo = new DataTable();
        int ifSucceed = dataQuery.Login(user.Replace("'", ""), pass.Replace("'", ""), userInfo);

        if (ifSucceed == 1)
        {
            if (userInfo.Rows.Count == 1)
            {
                if (userInfo.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "admin")
                {
                    this.Hide();
                    Admin newform = new Admin(dataQuery, userInfo);
                    newform.Closed += (s, args) => this.Close();
                    newform.Show();
                }
            }
            else if (userInfo.Rows.Count > 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("There are more than 1 rows in the table");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please check");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please set the network");
    }
```

Comment: where is  connection.txt?

Comment: project/bin/Debug/connection.txt

Comment: You are trying to read a file from the current directory (no path given) so when your release application starts the required file should be in the same directory where your final app is located. Check if the file is present in the folder from where you start the app

Answer (score 0):

The application `exe` and the `connection.txt` file should be in the same folder

Comment: how do i make sure that connection.txt is in same folder.  While I run the project in VS, the connection.txt is created in debug folder of the project.  Is it something I have to do while I am creating exe?  The error I get is "path to c:\ProgramFiles(x86)\project\connection.txt is denied."

Comment: have you tried to run the application as Administrator ?